# Unable to remove peers from hbase shell command

Tags: hbase

I made a typo while creating a replication peer in hbase shell: The zookeeper string contains invalid characters. Now when trying to remove the peer I am getting this error message:

> ERROR: For input string: "2181[ptbvdep@sctbvap01" Here is some help
>   for this command: List all replication peer clusters.

Is there a way to remove the peer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the peer ID for the desired zookeeper in remove_peer command. You can fetch the peer id with "list_peer" command.

```
hbase> list_peers // gives the list of all peer cluster with ID
hbase> remove_peer ‘1’  // use the peer cluster ID
```

You can find more detailed documentation here.
https://learnhbase.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/hbase-shell-commands/

Hope it helps.